# Jetpack Compose 'Preview Configuration Picker' option is missing in Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 3

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

Im exploring Jetpack compose using Android Studio (version Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 3)

And I found out there should be an option to configure/customise the compose preview in Android Studio, which is called 'Preview Configuration Picker'. But i couldn’t find such option in my local Android studio for the **same source code** (As shown in this video -  [What’s new in Android development tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRNWzhrl6-s&t=228s))

(Another example of this option as gif:)
[image: below]

Can some one tell me how could I enable this? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the **Bumblebee** version (Canary Build). You can find it there.
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview